# Display Mutiple Values in one column using SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, reporting-services

I have a report in which I want to display value of 2 engineers in one column.I am using a cube to generate a matrix.

For Example

```
   Customer   Engineer     Support
    Citi       ABC           
    Citi       XYZ           EFG
```

I used the below code

```
=First(Fields!string.Value)+","+ Last(Fields!string.Value)
```

Then I am getting something like this

```
  Customer   Engineer     Support
  Citi      ABC,XYZ       EFG,EFG
```

But I want to display it like this

```
   Customer   Engineer     Support
    Citi       ABC,XYZ      EFG
```

How can I display like above?

Comment: This does not contain a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=IIF(First(Fields!string.Value) = Last(Fields!string.Value), First(Fields!string.Value), First(Fields!string.Value)+","+ Last(Fields!string.Value))
```